# Does Android ImageView check image rotation?

Tags: android

Does Android ImageView check image rotation? Or I should do it manually using ExifInterface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ImageView` just knows only having an image inside, not knowing whatever action of its.

1. In case you want to rotate image, this is one of my article written about it: http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/06/22/image-processing-rotate-image-on-the-fly/
2. In case you want to detect whether the image is rotate, create a `CustomImageView` inherits from the base `ImageView`, having a flag to check image rotation flag.